# Basis of $ℝ_{\leqslant n}[x]$ space

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $F_0, F_1,..., F_n$ be polynomials over ℝ and $deg F_i = i$.

Prove that {$F_0, F_1,..., F_n$} is a basis of $ℝ_{\leqslant n}[x]$.

**Thought** I know that $(1,X,X^2,X^3,··· ,X^n)$ is a basis of $ℝ_{\leqslant n}[x]$, and maybe I need to use induction but I can't understand how to use it right.

**Another  thought** Probably I misunderstood why polynomials with different degrees are linearly independent (from definition), if someone could me give a reference about that it'll be great.

Comment: You know that $ \{1,X,X^2,X^3,··· ,X^n \}$ is a basis of $ℝ_{\leqslant n}[x]$, hence $ \dim ℝ_{\leqslant n}[x]=n+1$. Hence you have only to show that the polynonials  $F_0, F_1,..., F_n$ are linearly independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Take a nonzero linear combination

$a_0F_0 +a_1F_2 +\ldots +aF_n$

with coefficients $a_0,\ldots,a_n$.

Since this linear combination is nonzero, there is a largest index $i$ such that $a_i\ne 0$. Then $a_iF_i\ne 0$ is a polynomial of degree $i$, while any other nonzero polynomial $a_jF_j$ with $j<i$ has degree $<i$. In particular, the term in $a_iF_i$ involving $x^i$ cannot be cancelled in the above expression and so $a_i$ must be zero contradicting the hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to prove that these polynomials are linearly independent, which should be easier.
Then you'll know that they form a basis because there is $n+1 = dim(\mathbb{R}_{n}[X])$ of them.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).